# Python: Ensure each pairwise distance is >= some minimum distance

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a 2D array of ~200,000 points, and wish to "jitter" these points such that the distance between any point and its nearest neighbor is >= some minimum value.

Before writing this algorithm from scratch, I wanted to ask: Are there any canonical approaches or often-used algorithms to implement this behavior? I thought it would make sense to start by reviewing those algorithms before setting out on this.

Any suggestions others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What dyou mean with "*jitter*"? Changing the coordinate? What if there is a point in the middle, and a circle of points such that the point can not escape, and thus will always result in an invalid state?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes by jitter I mean rearrange the points minimally such that any point's nearest neighbor is >= some value. While some inputs will require more deformation than others, there should be no invalid states. The goal is to find a valid arrangement that minimizes the deformation of the input array positions.

Comment: I'm thinking quantize the space out into a grid in which each point's distance from the neighbors = the minimum distance between points, then assign each point to the nearest unoccupied slot in the grid.

Comment: @duhaime: that would work in a reasonable amount of time, but doesn't get you minimal movement -- if that's your "fitness" criterion.  If you don't care about far-flung points being moved across five time zones to the nearest grid point, then implement this: it's straightforward, easy enough to maintain, and fast.

Comment: @Prune, yes, you're quite right. This would be a fast approximate method. I am interested in other more expensive methods that further minimize the aggregate distance each point moves, but I don't have great intuitions on what kinds of algorithms might be appropriate for that task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a technique called ["Lloyd iteration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) to solve this problem. The idea behind the algorithm is quite simple; to run Lloyd iteration on a set of points, we:

1. Build a Voronoi diagram of the points
2. Center each point in its Voronoi cell
3. Repeat until points are sufficiently separated

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/347e1061d51139eb77ab6bf65b11debc) has some sample code (with visualizations):

```
from lloyd import Field
from scipy.spatial import voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import umap, os

def plot(vor, name, e=0.3):
  '''Plot the Voronoi map of 2D numpy array X'''
  plot = voronoi_plot_2d(vor, show_vertices=False, line_colors='y', line_alpha=0.5, point_size=5)
  plot.set_figheight(14)
  plot.set_figwidth(20)
  plt.axis([field.bb[0]-e, field.bb[1]+e, field.bb[2]-e, field.bb[3]+e])
  if not os.path.exists('plots'): os.makedirs('plots')
  if len(str(name)) < 2: name = '0' + str(name)
  plot.savefig( 'plots/' + str(name) + '.png' )

# get 1000 observations in two dimensions and plot their Voronoi map
np.random.seed(1144392507)
X = np.random.rand(1000, 4)
X = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(X)

# run 20 iterations of Lloyd's algorithm
field = Field(X)
for i in range(20):
  print(' * running iteration', i)
  plot(field.voronoi, i)
  field.relax()
```

The upshot is that points move just as they do in the following gif:

[image]

NB: The gif above shows unconstrained Lloyd iteration, where the output domain may be very large. For some discussion and code to construct constrained Lloyd iterations in Python, I wrote a little [blog post](https://douglasduhaime.com/posts/lloyd-iteration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite similar to bubble charts construction ([examples](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/force-bubbles/)): placing N spheres of specified radius in a chart such that:

- they don't overlap
- the total chart is a small as possible

I'm not very knowledgeable in this area, so I can't make an exhaustive list of algorithms for this problem. I will present the only one I know in this post, and how you could adapt it to your problem.

One common approach used by javascript chart libraries seems to be physics based (example: [d3.js force clusters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-force-cluster)). In a nutshell (from my understanding), they:

1. randomly (or with an heuristic) give an initial position to the spheres.
2. run a small physics simulation considering the spheres as objects, by applying the following forces:

   - Gravity to attracts every sphere.
   - Collision to separate overlapping spheres.
   - "Fluid" friction: slow down every object that has a speed. This ensures that the simulation stops at some point (prevent oscillations).

This could be adapted to solve your problem: consider each point as the center of a sphere of diameter `D` (`D` being the minimal distance you want between each point). All spheres have the same mass (you can simply ignore the mass, and work directly with accelerations instead of forces).

1. The initial position of your spheres are your input data.
2. Physics: just discards the gravity, as you don't want/need to "pack" the points.

As I said, I'm not very familiar with bubble charts. It might be interesting to look for alternative algorithms on this topic, and see if they suit your case.

Answer (score 0):

1. compute pairwise distances between all points -
   sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances
2. compute minimum of all pairwise distances
3. if minimum is small enough, exit
4. compute pairwise vectors between each two points so they point away
   from each other
5. divide by pairwise distances so they are unit
   vectors
6. for each point, compute how far to nudge it as sum over
   other points of: pairwise vector/pairwise distance squared * some
   constant (the force - constant should be set so that when points are at the minimum distance force is small but not infinitesimal)
7. nudge all the points by amount
   computed in 6. should also cap the nudge at maybe minimum/10, so if 2 points end up in same spot, they don't get nudged an infinite distance apart
8. repeat until minimum is small enough

Should converge in all cases but will expand canvas as necessary. Also it is memory and compute intensive for e.g. 200,000 points, but a sparse matrix that ignores large vectors/small forces makes it more tractable.

Comment: Thanks for this @RockyMcNuts. If you have the time and willpower, I'd love to see this in action in some kind of snippet, as I'm not sure how to follow what you've laid out, but I'm intrigued. What led you to this line of thought?

Comment: similar to Vincent Saulue-Laborde but thought he wasn't as explicit, didn't have enough karma to leave a comment on his post LOL.

if starting with higher-dimensional data, TSNE might be appropriate, but that's more about bringing points together than assuring minimum separation.

if starting with 1-dimensional data, one can arrange them in a circle and then jitter randomly toward/away from center.

seems an interesting problem with no standard approach, found this post highly ranked so worth a comment, if I implement will revert.